# Place navbar above <p> element and image

Tags: html, css

I have this nav bar formatting on my webpage. [image: Desired Format] But I would like it to look like this.The navbar is above the image and corresponding paragraph element. [image: Desired Format]

The picture is the figure element. Here's the [index.html](http://pastebin.com/j1evmwnr) and [css file](http://pastebin.com/Ain70A1A). Thanks!

Comment: just put the `figure` underneath your `nav` in stead of inside it... (also, is a `li`st of links actually a `p`aragraph ?) https://jsfiddle.net/eey59L7y/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have wrapped the `image` in `nav` just put it outside.

Here is your desired menu **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/zgfu6saw/)**

```
 <nav id="mainnav">
   <p>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a> |
      <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a> |
      <a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a> |
      <a href="reserve.html">Reservations</a> |
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Local Weather</a> |
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Directions</a>
    </p>
          </nav>
  <figure id="main">
    <img src="http://arabland.cc/css/images/testimonial-bg.jpg" width="369" height="268" alt=""/>
  </figure>
```